# Create a Context Menu when Click Long in a Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to show a context menu (OnClickLong)with delete and edit option, in a custom list i created with a custom list adapter. i will post the code

**SpotListFragment**

```
package com.pap.myspots.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.pap.myspots.R;
import com.pap.myspots.R.layout;
import com.pap.myspots.database.DBAdapter;
import com.pap.myspots.listView.SpotList;
import com.pap.myspots.listView.SpotListAdapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SpotListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    String nome;
    String local;
    Button createToast;
    List<String> nomes ;
    List<String> locais ;
    ListView listView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spotlist, container, false);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        db.open();
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllTitles();
        nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome"));
            nomes.add(uname);
        }

        Cursor cursor2 = db.getAllTitles();
        locais = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(cursor2.moveToNext()){
            String ulocal = cursor2.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("local"));
            locais.add(ulocal);
        }

       SpotListAdapter adapter = new SpotListAdapter(getActivity(), generateData());

       // 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
       listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spotList);

       // 3. setListAdapter
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;

        }

    private ArrayList<SpotList> generateData(){
        ArrayList<SpotList> items = new ArrayList<SpotList>();
        int i = 0;
        while(nomes.size()>i){
            items.add(new SpotList(new String(nomes.get(i)),new String(locais.get(i))));
            i++;
        }
        return items;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    //Deleted individual cart items



}
```

**SpotListAdapter**

```
package com.pap.myspots.listView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.pap.myspots.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SpotListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpotList> {
     private final Context context;
     private final ArrayList<SpotList> itemsArrayList;

     public SpotListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SpotList> itemsArrayList) {

         super(context, R.layout.list_row, itemsArrayList);

         this.context = context;
         this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         // 1. Create inflater 
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         // 2. Get rowView from inflater
         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

         // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
         TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
         TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.place);

         // 4. Set the text for textView 
         labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getNome());
         valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getLocal());

         // 5. retrn rowView
         return rowView;
     }
}
```

**SpotList(Beans)**

```
package com.pap.myspots.listView;

public class SpotList {

    public SpotList(String nome, String local) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.local = local;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local = local;
    }

    private String nome;
    private String local;


}
```

Comment: You haven't tried on making a context menu? Please try and if you face any problem then we will .help

Comment: i can create it, the problem is that i dont know the right class and method ill do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first of all register your listView for a context menu in the onCreate method:

```
registerForContextMenu(yourListView);
```

---

Create the contextmenu by overridig the onCreateContextMenu:

```
@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    _listPosition = info.position;      // Get Index of long-clicked item

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose Action");   // Context-menu title
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");  // Add element "Edit"
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 1, "Delete");        // Add element "Delete"
}
```

---

React on clicks in context-menu:

```
 @Override  
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
      if(item.getTitle() == "Edit") // "Edit" chosen
      {
         // Do stuff
      }
      else if(item.getTitle() == "Delete")  // "Delete" chosen
      {
          // Do stuff
      }
      else 
      {
         return false;
      }

      return true;  
 }
```

Comment: +1, BTW, is depending on the `item.getTitle() == "Edit"` (which might change in a multi-language app) rather than on some index/key/tag is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Next time just spend few minutes and google it yourself:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu
- http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/

Override **onCreateContextMenu()** to create the menu and **onContextItemSelected()** to handle the click event

You also need to register listView for the contextual menu. You can do it in fragment's **onActivityCreated()** method:

```
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your custom ListView with Context Menu. Use Method `registerForContextMenu(listView);` . Call this method in `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

I would define the `onLongClickListener` in the `getView()` method of your overriden `ArrayList` extension. Just register the view inside the long click listener, using `registerForContextView(convertView)`.

Now in your Activity code, simply define the context menu as you would in any other case:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  ...    
  menu.setHeaderTitle(...);
  menu.add(...);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  final int mId = item.getItemId();

  switch (mId) {
    case 0: 
    ...
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More precision:

```
 @Override  
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        TreeViewList v1=(TreeViewList) v; //my custom listview
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        final LinearLayout viewLayout = (LinearLayout) v1.getChildAt(info.position-v1.getFirstVisiblePosition());//if in list many items
        final TextView descriptionView = (TextView) viewLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_description);
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, descriptionView.getText());  
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
        }
```